# Re-enable button when returning to page MVC5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the below code that disables my next page/submit button until a field is populated, however the problem I have is that I have the option to return to this page but the next button becomes disabled again, even though field is no longer blank, any advice?  Thanks in advance

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#Notification_NumberOfContractors').keyup(function () {

       var empty = false;           
       $('#Notification_NumberOfContractors').each(function () {
           if ($(this).val() == '') {
               empty = true;
           }
       });

       if (empty) {
           $('#ProjectDetailsNextPage').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       } else {
           $('#ProjectDetailsNextPage').removeAttr('disabled');
       }
   });
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're binding your test to the key up event.  It won't run any test until you type something in one of the boxes somewhere.  You could run the test when the page loads, and on key up, or you could leave the javascript, and test it on the server before you send it down for the initial screen.

Answer (score 0):

> but the next button becomes disabled again, even though field is no longer blank, any advice?

You can trigger the  keyup event at the end of handler declaration:

```
$('#Notification_NumberOfContractors').keyup(function () {

   var empty = false;           
   $('#Notification_NumberOfContractors').each(function () {
       if ($(this).val() == '') {
           empty = true;
       }
   });

   if (empty) {
       $('#ProjectDetailsNextPage').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   } else {
       $('#ProjectDetailsNextPage').removeAttr('disabled');
   }
}).trigger('keyup');
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```